# Can't do page click login link with Puppeter

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I just want to click button for login pop-up, but nothing happens if I try to do this. Used copy JS path. There is no problems for me "clicking" other buttons. Any hints and help ?

```
await page.waitFor('body > div.b-app > div > div > div.b-main-content > header > div.clearfix > div > div.b-header--links--item.b-header--links--login > button');
await page.click('body > div.b-app > div > div > div.b-main-content > header > div.clearfix > div > div.b-header--links--item.b-header--links--login > button');
```

On original page it looks like:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link link-red-no-underline b-login-register--button b-login-register--key b-login-register--login">
                    <svg class="b-icon" style="">
    <use xlink:href="#key"></use>
</svg>
                    Prisijungti
                </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

seems await page.waitFor(2000);  helped to resolve